# EntityFramework is using the wrong data context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I have an assembly data project in my solution that is being consumed by a different project.  The data project contains three different `edmx` entries.

I'm calling a function import in one, but inside the `edmx.cs` I'm receiving an error on the calling line:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction
```

> ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext

is returning the type of a different context entirely!  Thus it cannot find the function I'm calling.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?  I don't know why it would be in one context and yet return the other type when the `ObjextContext` is checked.

Comment: I don't think it's the framework who's using the wrong data context ;)

Comment: That's very helpful.  Thanks for the input.  I am very clearly calling the context I want to, but the cast is returning a different one.  Once again, thanks for the incredibly helpful input.

Comment: What is the type of `IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext`?  What is the type of `this.ObjectContext`?  Is there a relationship between these two types?

Comment: This is autogenerated code in the edmx.cs, Tarec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foolish mistake on my part.  My connection string in the consuming project was pointing to the wrong csdl.  The code compiles fine, you can update from the model perfectly, but it will break at runtime when the consuming project's config is used.  Even though you can trace into the edmx.cs file for your data project, it will cast to the other model on the execution line.